# Give row color after onClick row and make request other page and stay color changed

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I need Give row color after onClick row and make request other page and stay color changed 
Notes: Currentaly change row color and disable  color changed after refres page

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
      var id = $row['id'];
      function myPopup(id) {
           if (id) {
                location.href = "address.php?id="+id;
           }
      }
 </script>
 <script>
      $(document).ready(function () {
           $('#imagetable tr').click(function () {
                $(this).css('background-color', 'Green');
           });
      });
 </script>
```

```php
 <?php
      $resualt=mssql_query("SELECT * FROM Address ") ;
      echo "<table border='1' class='imagetable' 
      id='imagetable'      width='50%'>\n";
      echo '<tr>';
      echo '<th>ID</th>'.'<th>User ID</th>'.'<th>Street</th>'.'<th>Quarter</th>'.'<th>Mobile   Number</th>'.'<th>Email</th>'.'<th>From</th>'.'<th>To</th>'.'<th>Notes</th>';
      echo '</tr>';

      while ($row = mssql_fetch_assoc($resualt)) {
           echo "<tr onClick='myPopup($row[id])'>\n"."<td >{$row['id']}</td>\n"."<td>  {$row['user_id']}</td>\n"."<td>{$row['street']}</td>\n"."<td>{$row['quarter']}</td>\n"."<td>{$row['Phone_number']}</td>\n"."<td>  {$row['email']}</td>\n"."<td>{$row['from_date']}</td>\n"."<td>{$row['to_date']}</td>\n"."<td>{$row['other_info']}</td>\n".'</tr>'."\n";
      }
      echo "</table>\n";
 ?>
```

Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your PHP check if the given ID matches the ID in the while loop. When that matches, add a style parameter or a CSS class depending on your situation.

Examples:

```
 // Your code leading up to the while loop is here ...

 while ($row = mssql_fetch_assoc($resualt)) {
     echo "<tr onClick='myPopup($row[id])" . ($_GET['id'] == $row[id] ? "style='background-color: green'":"") .  "'>\n".
          "<td >{$row['id']}</td>\n".

 // The rest of the code in your loop continues here ...
```

It is not the most beautiful or safe code, but it suits the code you already have i think.

Comment: Please give some more info then. I ran this locally and it worked. Can you tell me what isn't working? Is the _GET populated? Is the if statement not working for you? etc

Comment: `($_GET['id'] == $row[id] ? "style='background-color: green'":"")` This is a shorthand if statement

Comment: Then i am sorry to say that i realy cannot help you any furthr. The example is working here. Please take a good look at the concept which i am trying to share. Maybe you can find a correct implementation for yourself then. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks mvbrakel  I am try

Comment: Think you mvbrakel its work perfectly problem in order  Comma Very Very Very Thanks